# Number formatting help in Excel

Tags: excel

I'm using a custom number format and conditional formatting in cells so that the displayed value is different than the actual value. The custom number format is `[<=500]$#,",000"` and changes a number like $125,600 to $126,000 (i.e. it rounds it to the nearest thousand). However, with negative numbers, it leaves the "-" in front of the number. I'd like to address it so that it changes it to parenthesis instead of the negative sign, but with the customer format I'm using, I haven't had success incorporating it. I tried different versions on my own and none of them help.

Comment: Are you missing a `"` in that format somewhere? That doesn't work for me.

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks for the response. It's not missing a " as it works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you're after

```
[>=500]$#,",000";[<=-500]($#,",000")
```

The formatting after the semi-colon applies to negative numbers, by using a different condition `<=-500`. The first condition, `>=500`, will only be appropriate for positive numbers.

If you want to wrap your negative numbers in square brackets rather than parentheses, you need to escape the brackets like this

```
[>=500]$#,",000";[<=-500]\[$#,",000"\]
```